# symfony routing problem

Tags: php, symfony1, url-routing

Please help a symfony noob with a basic question about routing an URLs..

I would like to be able to have nice urls in the following format:

```
shop/category/:name
```

and in my routing.yml i have:

```
shop_category:

  url: /shop/category/:name/
  param: { module: shop, action: category }
  class: sfDoctrineRoute
  options: { model: Category, type: object }
```

in my indexSuccess.php view i have:

```
 <?php foreach($categories as $category) { ?>
  <a href="<?php url_for('shop_category',$category)?>">link</a>
 <?php } ?>
```

but the href link does not render when i mouse over the link..

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: It's rather a good practice to use [alternative syntax for control structures](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) within templates. (`foreach (): .... endforeach;`)It makes code more readable.

Comment: Please make at least a rudimentary debugging effort before asking a question.

Answer (score 4):

`url_for()` helper doesn't echo generated URL, it **returns** it. So simply add `echo` instruction:

```
<?php echo url_for(...) ?>
```